# Raspberry Pi Python Continue to Loop the move function until specific command stops it

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i'm trying to build a python script for a robot that will move continuously after getting data to the server.

Currently i'am able to make it moved using function moved and make it fetch to the server in a JSON Response.

What i really want to happen is to have something like a trigger that will continue to run the function move after i stop it.

Here's my current code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import serial
import movement as m
import time
import requests

#ttyACM0
#ttyUSB0

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
global myData
myData = ""
m.stop()                             
#m.forward(0.5)
m.right(0.1)
def move(myData = ""):
    #Start
    #far 
    while m.farTrack() == '1101':
        print ("Left")
        myData = ""
        m.left(0.01)
        break
    while m.farTrack() == '1011':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.01)
        break 
    while m.farTrack() == '1110':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.01)
        break 
    while m.farTrack() == '0111':
        print ("Left")
        myData = ""
        m.left(0.01)
        break 
    while m.farTrack() == '0011':
        print ("Left")
        myData = ""
        m.left(0.01)
        break
    while m.farTrack() == '1100':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.01)
        break
    while m.farTrack() == '0110':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.01)
        break
    while m.farTrack() == '0010':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.01)
        break
    while m.farTrack() == '1111':#if counter
        print ("Left")
        myData = ""
        m.left(0.01)
        break
    while m.lineTrack() == '1110':
        print ("Right")
        myData = ""
        m.right(0.01)
        break 


def saveData(myData):
    url = 'http://aviarthardph.net/robot/post.php'
    dataw = {'tag': myData}
    r = requests.post(url, data=dataw)
    print r.text
    print("Saving")



def main():
    while(arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
        global myData
        myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
        print ("Tag Idendified: ", myData)
        if(myData != ''):
            #saveData(myData)
            continue
    myData = myData
    while True:
        r = requests.get('http://aviarthardph.net/robot/table.php?tableInfo')
        data = r.json()
        print(data)
        if data['status'] == '0':
            while True:
                r = requests.get('http://aviarthardph.net/robot/table.php?tableInfo');
                data = r.json()
                if(data['table'] == '1' or data['table'] == 2 or data['table'] == 3 or data['table'] == 4):
                    if(data['movement'] == 'L'):
                        print ('move left')
                        move()
                        print('continue')


                 else:
                    print('move Right')
                    move()

            else:
                print ('move right')
            break
    print ("Identified RFID :", myData)
    print("Far Track", m.farTrack())
    print("Line Track", m.lineTrack())
    print("\n")
    #move(myData)   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output i'm visualizing is to make the `def move` function run continuously until the status changes from 0 to 1.

The json contains multiple data limit of 10 so i need to check the value of each data

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I would use a thread for the movement. Something like this (pseudocode)

```
def MoveThread():
   while(Enable):
      if(m.farTrack() == "0111"):
         <do something>


def main:
    if(Datavalid):
       t = Thread(target = MoveThread)
       t.start()
```

If you want to stop the movement, clear the `Enable`-Flag and let the thread join your main.